# How do I export my iOS project in Xcode 6.1.1?

Tags: ios, export, xcode6.1

I fell pretty stupid but I am to the point where I want to send my app to some friends to be tested. I was wondering if it is possible to do so without a developers account. If so, how do I do this. If it does take an account, how would I export it once I get one?

Comment: Do some research on Adhoc Distribution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without a developer account, you can't.

After you get your developer account, you have to create your **Distribution Certificate** and **Ad Hoc Provisioning Profile** based on the UDID collected from your friend's device.

Alternatively, you can use TestFlight feature in iTunes Connect. Requires Developer Account as well.